# CSS template block tag

Tags: python, css, django, tags, include

Sorry guyz, I am still newbie in django, I want make a website using django and find some problem, hope you guyz understand:

1. this is the base.html :

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
   
    <!-- My CSS -->
    {% block css_app%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css\styles.css" %}" /> {% endblock %}
    
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS Icon -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <title>{% block title %}Achmad Irfan Afandi {% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-flow">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- Contain-Menu -->
        {% include 'snippets/contain-menu.html' %}
        <!-- End Contain-Menu -->

        <!-- Contain-Isi -->
        {% include 'snippets/contain-isi.html' %}
        <!-- End Contain-Isi -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

2. In that base.html above, I use include tag for contain-isi: and this is code for contain-isi:

```
{% block img_page %}
<div class="col-8 text-end col-isi">
  <div class="text-start img">Home</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

3. I use that base.html for another app, but the prolem is, can I use and change img_page for another app in fact the that block is not inside base.html directly
4. And another problem is : I want to modify css file in app , so I give block tag in link css like this:

```
<!-- My CSS -->
    {% block css_app%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css\styles.css" %}" /> {% endblock %}
```

When I modifyy that tag in app with new css files, all the original css styles is gone even though I want to change only a few components, so what should I do so that the css in general still uses the original css and only certain components change

I try to use 2 links in the apps, first from original css and second from app_css, but not work